# Creating a Slack Webhook programmatically

Tags: slack-api, slack

Is there a way I can use the Slack API to create an incoming and outgoing webhook for a channel I just created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not think that feature exists, but you can just use any existing webhook with the newly created channel or use the Event API to get the same result.

**Incoming Webhooks**

You can redirect an incoming webhook to any channel by providing the channel name as parameter in your call. (see [Channel override](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#customizations_for_custom_integrations))

**Outgoing Webhooks**

Your existing [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) will work with any channel, as long as you use triger words when you created them. If that is not an option, I would recommend to look at the new [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) that would allow you to get the same functionality as with outgoing webhooks, but without having to provide a channel name in the first place. Check out the event types [message.channels](https://api.slack.com/events/message.channels) and [message.groups](https://api.slack.com/events/message.groups).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to go with the trigger word when creating them. But I will look at the Event API