# is there an api method for slack that takes a channel name as an argument and returns a token?

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins job to be able to take a slack channel name as a parameter, and then post messages, about who kicked off the build, and if it completed etc, how can my job get a slack token, for any given channel?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not how tokens work with the Slack API. Tokens are always user based and for the whole workspace. So once you have a token you app can post to any public channel.

To get a token a user needs to install your Slack app. *)

Alternatively can create "dynamic" webhooks, that can post to any channel in a workspace. Check out this answer for details:

[Creating a Slack Webhook programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370319/creating-a-slack-webhook-programmatically/40401764#40401764)

However, those are officialy legacy and might stop working some time in the future. So your safest approach would be to create a Slack app and install it to the workspace to get your token.

*) There once was a concept called "workspace tokens". You still find it in the documentation, but it never left the BETA stage and was canceled. Best to ignore it.